# How to refresh the jsp page before reading the contents?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am using the below code to read the contents
from jsp page using eclipse

```
 public static String getOTP(String p_mobileNumber)
  {
      String    l_str_result;
      StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    // many of these calls can throw exceptions, so i've just
    // wrapped them all in one try/catch statement.
    try
    {
      // create a url object
      URL url = new URL("https://page.jsp");

      // create a urlconnection object
      URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

      // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

      String line;

      // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
      {
        content.append(line + "\n");
      }
      bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    l_str_result=content.toString();
}
```

Can any one please tell me what modification I have to do for above code to refresh jsp page before reading the contents?

Comment: I think you need to be quite a lot clearer about what you're trying to achieve, and what you're seeing currently, if you want useful help here. I'm also not sure what this has to do with Selenium.

Comment: "Refresh" is a term meaning that you instruct your browser to bypass the cache. In your function you are not using the browser, and there's no cache. So what do you mean by "refresh"?

Comment: am trying to read sms code from jsp page for payment test cases  in testing Environment using perfecto cloud with selenium

Comment: Post the html code of rendered JSP page. we can give the selenium code to read the sms text from the page.

Comment: The code you posted does not have any relationto Selenium WebDriver. Are you sure the tags are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted does not contain selenium code. If you intent to use selenium you can use the following code.

```
WebDriver driver  = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
driver.get("https://page.jsp");
driver.navigate().refresh();

String pageSource  = driver.getPageSource();
```

I have used HTMLUnitDriver which is a headless browser. You can change to `new FirefoxDriver()` if you want to use firefox.